# Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] mysql

Tags: hibernate

hiThis error every few days
after user submit and get query
Every 3-2  hours

im useing
tomcat 9.0enter image description here
jsf 2.9
hibernate 5.4.13
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9Mlc.jpg)

Comment: Please add your stack trace as a text.

Comment: Please add code you trying to run